# Using dynamic value in css in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, height, angular2-template, angular2-directives

How would i go about updating the CSS dynamically of an overlay that I have appear only when clicked on.
Here is a portion of my html:

```
<nav class="navigation" [class.navigation--overlay]="isItOpen">
</nav>
```

Essentially I would like my class `.navigation--overlay` to be set to the height of the window `(window.innerHeight)`

Can I essentially set a variable on my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'poodles',
  templateUrl: 'app/doodles.html',
  styles: [`
    .navigation--overlay {
      background: $MyColor;
    }
  `]
  providers: [DuhService]
})
```

Comment: What does "I would like my class .navigation--overlay to be set to the height of the window (window.innerHeight)" mean? You either set or remove a class. You usually don't set a value for a class.

Comment: Yes when I set my class .navgation--overlay I want to have a function that can get the value of window.innerHeight then my class will have height set to that value.

Comment: How can a class have a height?

Comment: You mean all elements that match a selector with that class should get that height applied?

Comment: Yes all elements that match the selector should have that class applied.

Comment: If you do what I showed in my answer you should get the same effect. Instead of adding a class you set the `height` directly. There is currently no way to have dynamic CSS in Angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
<nav class="navigation" [ngStyle]="isItOpen ? {'height.px': windowHeight} : {}">
</nav>
```

Comment: This didn't work. The page was just hung for me. Do I need to define ngStyle elsewhere?

Comment: I guess it would be better to listen on window resize events and set a property `windowHeight` and then use `ngStyle]="isItOpen ? {height: windowHeight} : {}"`. I don't know how you implemented `getWindowHeight()` but calling a method from the view is prone to cause troubles because it can be inefficient. I guess your browser hung because this was too slow (it's called quite often).

Comment: I just set height:300px without calling getWindowheight just to see if it will go though and it didn't.

Comment: How exactly are you doing that? `[ngStyle]="isItOpen ? {height: '300px'} : {}"`? Can you please try `null` instead of `{}`?

Comment: <nav  class="nav" [class.nav--overlay]="isMobileMenuOpen" [ngStyle]="isMobileMenuOpen ? {'height': 300px} : {}>

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/NBrUB6rtoMKsMjKnbkBT?p=preview. The property names needs '`' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use CSS to do this?

Set the class then just have the class height: 100%?

Something like:

```
  styles: [`
    .navigation--overlay {
      background: $MyColor;
      height:100%;
    }
  `]
```

Comment: That is what I initially had, but I am trying to solve for an iphone specific bug where when I scroll up a bit and then open my overlay. The overlay is not 100% height even though I set it. I can still see the content behind it at the bottom.